# Python series where values are lists, get another series with list of indexes correspond to each item list

Tags: python, pandas

Sorry the title is hard to understand—not sure how to phrase this one. Say I have a series that looks like this

```
s = pd.Series(index = ['a','b','c'], data = [['x','y','z'], ['y','z'], ['x','z']]).
```

I would want something like this

```
{'x':['a','c'], 'y':['a','b'], 'z':['a','b','c']}
```

I.e. I can see which keys correspond to each element from the series of lists. Any ideas how I could do this as efficiently as possible? Thanks!

Comment: I’m curious, how did you end up in this situation?

Comment: Danny, you should consider giving WeNYoBen a checkmark for this answer, it's an awesome one deserving one and a great question as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us use `explode`

```
s.explode().reset_index().groupby(0)['index'].agg(list).to_dict()
{'x': ['a', 'c'], 'y': ['a', 'b'], 'z': ['a', 'b', 'c']}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using default dict for speed:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
q = s.explode()
for k, v in q.items():
    d[v].append(k)

dict(d)
```

Output:

```
{'x': ['a', 'c'], 'y': ['a', 'b'], 'z': ['a', 'b', 'c']}
```

Timings:

> %timeit
>   s.explode().reset_index().groupby(0)['index'].agg(list).to_dict()
>   3.94 ms ± 119 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
>
> %%timeit   d = defaultdict(list) method
>   300 µs ± 33.4 µs per l0op (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000
>   loops each)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a second solution as well:

```
x = s.explode() 

pd.DataFrame({'X':x.index, 'Y':x.values}).groupby('Y')['X'].apply(list).to_dict()


# {'x': ['a', 'c'], 'y': ['a', 'b'], 'z': ['a', 'b', 'c']}
```

Comment: That looks a lot like @WeNYoBen's solution and doesn't add much value.

Comment: It's an original second solution, and while i'm in love with WeNYoBen's answer, i thought one easier to follow for those learning pandas might be nice to have here as well